# Vue Part doesn't appear on main page

Tags: vue.js

Going through a Vue.js course I've stuck. Main problem is that I've never used vue.js before and 50% of this course is just throwing code snippets at me so I might go wrong with them. I've got the following script:

```
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      dates: [],
      closedIncidents: [{
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Slow response times',
        'end': '2018-8-2 13:00:12',
        'start': '2018-8-1 13:00:12',
        update_set: [{
          'description': 'We have noticed some connectivity issues',
          'date': '2018-8-1 13:00:12',
          'status': 'Investigating'
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var end = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 6))
    var start = new Date()
    for (this.dates = []; end <= start; start.setDate(start.getDate() - 1)) {
      this.dates.push(start)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getIncidents: function (i) {
      return this.closedIncidents.filter(a => moment(moment(a.start).startOf('day')).isSame(moment(i).startOf('day')))
    }
  },
  filters: {
    dateFormat: function (value) {
      return moment.utc(value).format('li')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This part of my app doesn't appear on my main page. There are no errors with imports because they all are the same and only this .vue file doesn't wanna work.

My question is - is everything alright with this script?

Comment: To me your script looks fine. Perhaps compare it to a different component which does work and see if you can spot any differences

Answer (score 1):

The script does't appear on your page maybe because you have some errors on template, could u show it too